# how VIP card helps in verification?

Tags: security, security-identifier

How does the 6 digit randomly generated security code from (disconnected)Verisign Identity Protection card helps in verification/validation of any user?
Why one cannot enter any random 6 digit value instead of generating that value from VIP card/device?
Is there any fixed pattern of getting those values from that VIP device/card so that the server can verify that number?

Comment: I think this should go to [security.se] instead.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a better fit for the [Information Security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: While you're there, make sure to read the various questions on multi-factor authentication, such as [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24652/two-factor-authentication-when-is-it-worth-it) or [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5621/does-two-factor-authentication-prevent-social-engineering-attacks)